# How to fix the edges of polygon?

Tags: python, geometry, polygon

Here's the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12gi6TDNLaYkz3qNkATryW_d-8QysH60L?usp=sharing

[image]

This is the current polygon. The coordinates are fetched from server. And I need to optimize the polygon in a way that the edges are sharp (currently those edges look rough). Ideally it should look like 6 rectangles put together side by side.

I have tried to use [buffer](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html?highlight=buffer#object.buffer) and [simplify](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html?highlight=simplify#object.simplify) but they are not getting the result that I want.

For example, if I use `polygon.simplify(0.3)`, the edges are "optimized", but the left boundary is now skewed.

[image]

Comment: bounding box of each polygon?

Comment: @gnight but I only have 1 polygon. That's the one

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood.